# target looped html attributes singularly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm actually finding it difficult to get the element attribute am targeting on click.

i built an auto search system and also i want to add a feature of delete..

after result is droped down as a looped element, i want to be able to click on a particular element delete button and be able to delete that from the database using its element data-id="each-number" , how can i target the attribute with JavaScript only for the particular element ignoring others

```
static delApi(delClassName, attribute){
      const del = document.querySelectorAll(delClassName);
      del.forEach(e =>{ 

      })

static delApi(delClassName, attribute){
      const del = document.querySelectorAll(delClassName);
      del.forEach(e =>{ 
           e.target.this.attribute //only
      })
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c96T0.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your code snippet at all; forEach has nothing to do with click event handlers. But your notion of `e.target` is actually pretty close. Here is an example of how that would work in the context of an event listener callback.

I'm using vanilla JavaScript with the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), because while you included the jQuery tag, all of your code above is vanilla. I'm also creating a single event listener and allowing the click event to bubble, and then I'm filtering out any events I might not be interested in.

All of this is a little more straightforward with jQuery, since it can handle all the filtering for you: e.g. `$(document.body).on('button', function(e) { /* ... */ })`.

I'm able to pull from the `data-id` attributes using [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.tagName==='BUTTON') console.log("delete", e.target.dataset.id);
});
```

```html
<button data-id="1">one</button>
<button data-id="2">two</button>
<button data-id="3">three</button>
<button data-id="4">four</button>
```